# Re-using byte array data from server

Tags: android, arrays, stub

I'm having trouble understanding how I can re-use byte data sent down from my server. I'm trying to set up a stub backend for an app and be able to store/return all the backend data locally for a specific user.

When setting a breakpoint and copying the value of my server response (`byte[]` type), it looks like

```
[-119, 80, 78, ...]
```

when copied into a text editor.

If I wanted to store this large array locally and return the value as a `byte[]` back to my server response handling, how can I accomplish this?

I tried storing the value in a `String` variable and using `getBytes()`, but the compiler complained that the string was too large. And I'm not even sure that would have returned what I wanted anyways.

Answer (score 0):

store it as a BLOB in SQLite. In this example --> http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/10/insert-and-retrieve-image-into-db.html BLOB is being used to store an image that has been converted to a byte array. 1mb limit..